# No postal code object in react Stripe elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a custom Stripe form. You can either bring in the whole card element or individual elements from Stripe elements. For styling purposes I am trying to bring in individual inputs so I can put them in a grid instead of the one line Stripe form.

There is card number, cvc, and expire date element but no postal code. Why is this present in the default card and not available as an individual element? Won't I need to submit a zip code for creating a payment? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the docs I'm referring to:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postal/zip code is not strictly required, and is out of scope for PCI compliance. The combined card input includes it for convenience (you can disable it), but in your own custom "split" form, you would need to bring your own `input` for postal/zip code and provide the value in the `billing_details`:

```
stripe.createPaymentMethod({
  type: 'card',
  card: cardNumberElement,
  billing_details: {
    name: 'First Last',
    address: { postal_code: '90210' }
  },
})
```

Like this example: https://jsfiddle.net/cdt43qL1/

Comment: Great response. One follow up... how does it work to create a payment without the CVC or expiration elements? I notice that you're only passing in the 'cardNumberElement' for card which is also what the docs say you can do. Are you supposed to add them into the object? I can't find any docs for that.

Comment: Stripe.js retrieves those elements automatically given the reference to the `cardNumber` element. It's not really documented explicitly but for example the spec for `createPaymentMethod` only shows ever using the `cardNumber` (or whole `card`) element: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method#stripe_create_payment_method-paymentMethodData-card

Answer (score 0):

It's hidden initially and it shows up after typing the card number.

Try with this card `4242 4242 4242 4242` on their sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-js-card-detailed-omfb3?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: I think you may have not read the entire question. That is true when you bring in the Card Element as a whole, but if you try to bring in individual elements like the CardNumberElement and CardExpiryElement no postal code appears